# Kendo Grid pass additional parametert in Read()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have applied external filtering to my kendo grid which works fine with a single textbox and a button. But now I need to add another text box and a button above the grid and based on the button clicked, call the respective method.For this I need to pass additional parameters to the grid.

I have added the 2 text boxes and 2 buttons as folllows and currently the Read() calls additionalData() which send value of one of the text box. How can I pass the value of the other text box?

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
@Html.TextBox("compSearch", (string)TempData["searchString"], new { id = "txtCompanySearch", style = "width: 400px;" })
    <button id="searchButton" class="button" type="button" style="text-align:center;" onclick="searchAccounts()">
        <span>Search</span>
        <img src="~/Content/images/magnifier.png" />
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnSrchString" value="@ViewBag.searchString" />

    @Html.TextBox("compSearchByMasterRateSheetId", (string)TempData["searchStringMRS"], new { id = "txtCompanySearchByMasterRateSheetId", style = "width: 400px;" })
    <button id="searchByMasterRateSheetIdButton" class="button" type="button" style="text-align:center;" onclick="searchAccountsMRS()">
        <span>Search By Master Rate Sheet ID</span>
        <img src="~/Content/images/magnifier.png" />
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnSrchStringMRS" value="@ViewBag.searchStringMRS" />

</div>

<div class="k-content">



  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Customer>()
                .Name("accountsGrid")
            .Columns(col =>
            {
                col.Bound(c => c.CustomerName).Title("Account").Width("30%");
                col.Bound(c => c.SourceSystemId).Title("B ID").Width("20%");
                col.Bound(c => c.AccountManager).Title("Account Manager").Width("30%");
                col.Bound(c => c.IsExternalQuotingEnabled).Title("External Quoting Enabled?").Width("20%");
            })
            .SetLevel3Defaults(Model)
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetCompanyInfo", "Home").Data("additionalData"))
                .PageSize(20)                  
            )
)
```

additionalData method is as follows:

```
function additionalData() {
        return {
            searchString: $("#txtCompanySearch").val()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, no need for ViewBag - just parameterized your server action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCompanyInfo(string searchString, string searchStringMRS)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
    { search by searchString }
    else
    { search by searchStringMRS }
    ...
}
```

Then alter your additional data:

```
function additionalData() {
        return {
            searchString: $("#txtCompanySearch").val(),
            searchStringMRS: $("#txtCompanySearchByMasterRateSheetId").val()
        }
    }
```

Those will be matched by name and passed into your READ action. Just keep 1 button to trigger the filtering.

Also, you can move your filters to the grid's toolbar. See [here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/toolbar-template).